# How do I implement the following algorithm in O(1) time?

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures, runtime

I have 2D array filled with integers. I want a way to find the average of some portion of the array in O(1) time. For instance, I have the array `A[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};` and the input of the algorithm would be boundaries. So `Algorithm(int top, int bottom, int left, int right)`. If top = 1 , bottom = 2, left = 1, right = 2 , then the portion would be from the second to the third row and from the second to the third column. So the average would be (5+6+8+9)/4.

Comment: You have to read the values, so don't see how this can be O(1).  It pretty much has to be O(n) (where "n" is the  number of values), unless you have some other constraints on the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There was a hint in the assignment that says one could speed this up by precomputing the average for all possible sub-regions. But I don't have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Look up Integral Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a sum of the prefix table.

The example would look like
your array

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 9

prefix array:

> 1 3 6
>
> 5 12 21
>
> 12 27 45

then when u want to calculate ur example:

```
X = (prefix[bottom][right] - prefix[bottom][left-1] - prefix[top-1][right] + prefix[top-1][left-1]) / (right - left + 1) * (bottom - top + 1);

X = (45 - 12 - 6 + 1) / 4 = 7;
```

Model using in filling prefix array:

```
  For(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
           prefix[i][j] = prefix[i-1][j] + prefix[i][j-1] + array[i][j] - prefix[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }
```

*code is written in C++ language
**n - number of lines, m - number of columns

Comment: What is _prefix array_ ? I don't understand how did you compute it.

Comment: Prefix array is an array which uses dynamic programming.
You need to make another array. I edited my post. Look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give a hint on what to do.  You *can* set up an auxiliary data structure to facilitate the computation.  However, that data structure requires more than O(1) time to calculate, so it only helps if you are doing the calculation many times.

The hint is that cumulative values are useful.  I'll give an example in one dimension.  You'll need to figure out how to extend it.  Say you have this data:

```
1      2      3      4      5
10    -3      6      6     -2
```

And you have the same problem.  How can this be solved in constant time?  Well, create another data structure with cumulative sums:

```
1      2      3      4      5
10     7     13     19     17
```

Now, if you want the *sum* from 2-5, you can just calculate 17 - 10 (that is, one index before the 2).  You can get the average by dividing this by (1 + 5 - 2).